# How can I adjust the size of highlighter data in jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I  have used  "sizeAdjust" attribute to adjust the size of data, but not getting the size channged , now it is too short  and I can't even read the values. How can I increase the size?
Please help me to resolve this isue...

Answer (score 0):

I have edited jquery.jqplot.css file and changed font size of highlighter.